# My javax.jms.MessageListener stops receiving messages from IBM MQ Server

Tags: listener, ibm-mq, message-queue, consumer

I am building a service that continuously consumes messages from a IBM MQ Queue. This service runs in a private cloud with 80 replicas (containers or PODs) listening to the queue. Observing the application logs, I can see about 20 PODs that are not consuming any messages, even though I can check the queue PUT metric counter which shows about 200 req/s (rush hour). Most of the messages stay in the queue for a while (20 seconds) and get expired.

During the non rush hour, the application receives about 40 req/s and can process all the messages without any being expired.

I wonder if there is a limit of active listeners that the IBM MQ Server support? If so, is there any way to increase this limit?

I create a JMSContext using this method:

```
public JMSContext buildContext() {
    if (this.context == null) {
        try {
            JmsConnectionFactory connection = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER).createConnectionFactory();
            String hostname = System.getenv("HOSTNAME");
            String appName = application.get();
            if (hostname != null && !hostname.trim().isEmpty()) {
                if (hostname.length() > 28) { // Tamanho máximo da propriedade WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME
                    appName = hostname.substring(hostname.length() - 28);
                } else {
                    appName = hostname;
                }
            }
            connection.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, host.get());
            connection.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_PORT, port.get());
            connection.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel.get());
            connection.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager);
            connection.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.USERID, userid);
            connection.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.PASSWORD, password);
            connection.setBooleanProperty(JmsConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, isUserAuthenticationMqcsp);
            connection.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            connection.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, appName);

            connection.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, CommonConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);

        LOGGER.info(String.format("buildContext - Parametros da fila a alta [%s],[%s],[%s],[%s],[%s]",
                host.get(), channel.get(), application.get(), queueManager, userid));

        this.context = connection.createContext();
        this.context.start();
        this.connectionFactory = connection;
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format("buildContext - error - code: [%s], message: [%s].", e.getErrorCode(), e.getMessage()));
    }
}
return this.context;
```

}

I also configure my message listener using a separate thread as following:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JMSContext context = factory.buildContext();

        this.creditoQueueConsumer = context.createConsumer(context.createQueue(Constantes.PREFIXO_QUEUE.concat(creditoQueue)));

        this.creditoQueueConsumer.setMessageListener(mqAltaPlataformaCreditoListener);
// mqAltaPlataformaCreditoListener is an implementation of MessageListener
        context.start();
}
```

The application seems to work fine, however there is a problem when some listeners suddenly stop receiving messages.
**I assume the MQ server works as a proxy and then distributes equally messages to all configured listeners, but for some reason, some of the listeners stop receiving messages.** The MQ server team mentioned that some connection timeouts are occurring in the server side, as shown in the following picture.

[image]

Is there any configuration that can be done in the client to avoid those timeouts ou to avoid the service to stop receiving messages?

Comment: Please show us the error messages that are occurring on the server side with the timeouts. Then we might be able to answer how to avoid them.

Comment: Your assumption about equal distribution is not accurate. MQ server will try to keep one getter 'hot' and only if it is not there, then give the message to the next getter. So some getters, if they are not needed due to the load, will not be given any messages at all, because other getters were able to deal with them.

Comment: What reason code do the getters show when they stop receiving messages. How is it that you know they have stopped receiving messages?

Comment: Thanks for the help @morag-hughson. There is no error on the client side and there is not an explicit reason that cause any given container running a listener service to stop receiving messages. Considering the "onMessage" method is asynch, there is no exception raisen there. 

On the server side, some connection timeouts occurred with the given reasons:
AMQ9271E: Channel 'CH.TO.SDV3A' timed out

EXPLANATION: A timeout occurred while waiting to receive from the other end of channel 'CH.TO.SDV3A'. The address of the remote end of the connection was '10.254.15.96'

Comment: Also other reason show up on the server side: @morag-hughson
`AMQ9999E: Channel to host 'CH.TO.SDV3A' to host '10.254.15.96' ended abnormally. 
Explanation: The channel program running under process ID 48550 for the channel 'CH.TO.SDV3A' ended abnormally. The host name is '10.254.15.96'; in some cases the host name cannot be determined and so its shown '????'.`

Comment: Thanks for providing the AMQ9271E error message - that is partially useful. Can you please edit your question and add it, and while you are doing so, please include the WHOLE of the message, specifically the ACTION section where it provides the TCP/IP call name and return code. These would be very useful.

Comment: Question edited with the full server log. Tks @MoragHughson

Comment: It seems that your SVRCONN channel is timing out because it hung out a recv() for 30 seconds and did not receive in data in that time. This sounds like the DISCINT parameter on a SVRCONN to me. It would help at this point if you could update your question with the full SVRCONN definition?

Comment: Pasting the text instead of images is preferred.   You can surround the text with triple backticks on the line above and below your text.   ```

Comment: @MoragHughson Note this error has been updated in 9.2 CDS to indicate if the timeout was because of DISCINT or for example HBINT missed.

Comment: @JoshMc - neat! I hadn't noticed that - sounds like a blog post! :-D

Comment: @MoragHughson just checked and it was at 9.2.2 CDS. It will now show [DISCINT TIMEOUT] if it is because of DISCINT.

Comment: @JoshMc - very nice. Unfortunately it seems the OP is using 9.1, so we'll need to see his SVRCONN definition to figure this timeout out.